# Ghostscript ps2pdf exec: gs: not found

Tags: exec, ghostscript

A thousand apologies if this has already been answered, but I can't find a solution for the life of me. Seems like it should be the simplest thing. I installed Ghostscript 9.23 and I'm trying to use the ps2pdf command to convert a document. The script runs up to the very last line then throws an error:

/C/Program Files/gs/gs9.23/lib/ps2pdfwr: line 44: exec: gs: not found

I've added the gs bin and lib directories to my windows PATH, but it looks like gs is still not finding something it needs. Thoughts?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be trying to use a Linux shell script on a Windows system, going by the path you state.

On Windows, the Ghostscript executable is called gswin32.exe, gswin32c. exe, gswin64.exe or gswin64c.exe depending on whether you have installed the 64 or 32-bit version, and whether you want to run the command line or windowed version.

Alternatively the missing ':' in the path specification might be a problem.

There's really very little point in using the shell script anyway, just do:

gswin32c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o

Comment: Hey Ken thanks for the response. You are correct I'm running this through a Cygwin bash shell. Reason being, I'm trying to piggy back off another script that is generating a bunch of .ps files and essentially add an additional step afterward to have Ghostscript convert them to .pdfs. 

I checked my Windows PATH and the ':' isn't missing there, not sure why it doesn't show up in the error message. 

When you mention that I can just use the command 

'gswin32c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o'

Rather than using the shell script, where would I run that from if not the shell script?

Comment: Where you have 'ps2pdf' replace it with an explicit call to gswin<bits>.exe, using the path where Ghostscript is installed. Or modify ps2pdf.sh so that it calls gswin<bits>,exe instead of 'gs'. Or write your own version of ps2pdf.sh. Or if you're on Windows 10, just use the Linux Ghostscript binary in WSL. Ah no you're using Cygwin, so I guess not Windows 10 with WSL then. You'll need to modify either the shell script calling ps2pdf, or the ps2pdf.sh shell script.